# Adding sender profile icon in php Mail

Tags: php, email, cakephp

I have a web application running over a cakePHP framework, having inside one automated mail sender service. I would like them to send them with a profile picture, if it was possible, but I haven't found any solution on the net.

To show what I want:

[image]

Any approach?

Comment: isn't that image as per google plus profile ? Create a google plus account from the account you are sending mail from